# Vaadin beanItemContainer

Tags: vaadin

I have 2 Entities Mission and Location in vaadin maven project witch I have the idlocation in Mission so when I fill my grid with a BeanItemContainer the result is like the picture ,
or I want to have only the name of the Entity B can you help me please?
Thank you,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uInBB.png)

Comment: please make your question more readable. In its current state it won't get much attention. Include some relevant code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to override the `toString()` method in `Location` class to returns the name or any concatenation string.
Hope this help you.

Comment: did you find this helpful, if so please check it an answer or vote up.

Comment: But now I have a problem that location column is empty but in database I have data .Can you help me please?

Comment: what did you write in `toString()` method of `Location` class?

Comment: return getName(); with an other entity it work correctly but with Mission non

Comment: Mr.Nebras have you any idea about my problem it's still empty the column ?

Comment: It should work. However, please post your building data container `code` and adding items to table `code`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
grid.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(entity.class));
grid.setColumns("name-property");
// grid.setColumnOrder("name-prperty");
```